# Why does this floating-point calculation give different results on different machines?

Tags: c#

I have a simple routine which calculates the aspect ratio from a floating point value. So for the value 1.77777779, the routine returns the string "16:9". I have tested this on my machine and it works fine.

The routine is given as :

```
    public string AspectRatioAsString(float f)
    {
        bool carryon = true;
        int index = 0;
        double roundedUpValue = 0;
        while (carryon)
        {
            index++;
            float upper = index * f;

            roundedUpValue = Math.Ceiling(upper);

            if (roundedUpValue - upper <= (double)0.1 || index > 20)
            {
                carryon = false;
            }
        }

        return roundedUpValue + ":" + index;
    }
```

Now on another machine, I get completely different results. So on my machine, 1.77777779 gives "16:9" but on another machine I get "38:21".

Comment: any reason you are passing aspectration as a float rather than a double?

Comment: Time to read <a href="http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html">What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic</a>.

Comment: @Oded - sorry I deleted my comment, I decided to promote it to an answer.

Comment: Quick tip: (double)0.1 is kinda waste. You should replace it with 0.1 (which default is a double) or 0.1d if you want to be explicit. Not sure if the compiler converts it to a double, but this could save you a cast...

Comment: @Peter: the compiler performs casts on constant expressions at compile time.

Comment: @Eric - thanks, I suspected that.

Comment: Hunh, I had never seen the postscript on differences among IEEE 754 implementations before. I didn't think that article had anything to say about this sort of pitfall. *"Unfortunately, the IEEE standard does not guarantee that the same program will deliver identical results on all conforming systems. Most programs will actually produce different results on different systems for a variety of reasons."*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's an interesting bit of the C# specifiction, from section 4.1.6:

> Floating-point operations may be
>   performed with higher precision than
>   the result type of the operation. For
>   example, some hardware architectures
>   support an “extended” or “long double”
>   floating-point type with greater range
>   and precision than the double type,
>   and implicitly perform all
>   floating-point operations using this
>   higher precision type. Only at
>   excessive cost in performance can such
>   hardware architectures be made to
>   perform floating-point operations with
>   less precision, and rather than
>   require an implementation to forfeit
>   both performance and precision, C#
>   allows a higher precision type to be
>   used for all floating-point
>   operations. Other than delivering more
>   precise results, this rarely has any
>   measurable effects.

It is possible that this is one of the "measurable effects" thanks to that call to Ceiling. Taking the ceiling of a floating point number, as others have noted, magnifies a difference of 0.000000002 by nine orders of magnitude because it turns 15.99999999 into 16 and 16.00000001 into 17. Two numbers that differ slightly before the operation differ massively afterwards; the tiny difference might be accounted for by the fact that different machines can have more or less "extra precision" in their floating point operations.

Some related issues:

- [C# XNA Visual Studio: Difference between "release" and "debug" modes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345534/c-xna-visual-studio-difference-between-release-and-debug-modes/2345645#2345645)
- [CLR JIT optimizations violates causality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225503)

To address your specific problem of how to compute an aspect ratio from a float: I'd possibly solve this a completely different way.  I'd make a table like this:

```
struct Ratio
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }
    public Ratio (int x, int y) : this()
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
    public double AsDouble() { return (double)X / (double)Y; }
}

Ratio[] commonRatios = { 
   new Ratio(16, 9),
   new Ratio(4, 3), 
   // ... and so on, maybe the few hundred most common ratios here. 
   // since you are pinning results to be less than 20, there cannot possibly
   // be more than a few hundred.
};
```

and now your implementation is

```
public string AspectRatioAsString(double ratio)      
{ 
    var results = from commonRatio in commonRatios
                  select new {
                      Ratio = commonRatio, 
                      Diff = Math.Abs(ratio - commonRatio.AsDouble())};

    var smallestResult = results.Min(x=>x.Diff);

    return String.Format("{0}:{1}", smallestResult.Ratio.X, smallestResult.Ratio.Y);
}
```

Notice how the code now reads very much like the operation you are trying to perform: from this list of common ratios, choose the one where the difference between the given ratio and the common ratio is minimized.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't use floating point numbers unless I really had to. They're too prone to this sort of thing due to rounding errors.

Can you change the code to work in double precision? (decimal would be overkill). If you do this, does it give more consistent results?

As to why it's different on different machines, what are the differences between the two machines?

- 32 bit vs 64 bit?
- Windows 7 vs Vista vs XP?
- Intel vs AMD processor? (thanks Oded)

Something like this *might* be the cause.

Comment: @Chris : yes, one is a 64 bit machine and the other where the results are not correct is a 32 bit machine. Also 64 bit machine is windows 7, 32 bit is windows xp. Both are intel processors. I will switch to double and use math.Round as suggested by others.

Comment: @JD - the 32bit vs 64bit might explain the problem, with the 32bit being less accurate.

Comment: @Chris: What is really strange is on another developer's 32 bit machine, running the routine via debug (in the IDE), the result are correct. However, outside the IDE the results are incorrect.

Comment: @JD - again, I'd say this was down to rounding error. I've had similar experiences in the past where code behaves differently inside the IDE and outside and differently under debug and release. It's due to slight differences in the way memory is initialised (if it is at all) for example.

Comment: @ChrisF a double on 32 bit is not less accurate than a double on 64 bit. They both use 8 byte and the same storage scheme.

Comment: @user492238 - that's true, but I was just offering suggestions of what *might* be the cause. If you've got two machines behaving differently you have to look at what's different.

Answer (score 5):

Try `Math.Round` instead of `Math.Ceiling`. If you end up with 16.0000001 and round up you'll incorrectly discard that answer.

Miscellaneous other suggestions:

- Doubles are better than floats.
- `(double) 0.1` cast is unnecessary.
- Might want to throw an exception if you can't figure out what the aspect ratio is.
- If you return immediately upon finding the answer you can ditch the `carryon` variable.
- A perhaps more accurate check would be to calculate the aspect ratio for each guess and compare it to the input.

Revised (untested):

```
public string AspectRatioAsString(double ratio)
{
    for (int height = 1; height <= 20; ++height)
    {
        int    width = (int) Math.Round(height * ratio);
        double guess = (double) width / height;

        if (Math.Abs(guess - ratio) <= 0.01)
        {
            return width + ":" + height;
        }
    }

    throw ArgumentException("Invalid aspect ratio", "ratio");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When index is 9, you would expect to get something like upper = 16.0000001 or upper = 15.9999999.  Which one you get will depend on rounding error, which may differ on different machines.  When it's 15.999999, `roundedUpValue - upper <= 0.1` is true, and the loop ends.  When it's 16.0000001, `roundedUpValue - upper <= 0.1`  is false and the loop keeps going until you get to `index > 20`.

Instead maybe you should try rounding upper to the nearest integer and checking if the absolute value of its difference from that integer is small.  In otherwords, use something like `if (Math.Abs(Math.Round(upper) - upper) <= (double)0.0001 || index > 20)`

Comment: Thanks. Just testing now. I should have been a bit more careful and tested more thoroughly rather.

Answer (score -1):

We had printf()-statements with floating point values that gave different roundings on computer 1 versus computer 2, even though both computers contained the same Visual Studio 2019 version and build.
The difference was found however in a slightly older Windows 10 SDK versus the newest version. How strange it may seem... After fixing that the differences were gone.

Comment: This answer is pretty arbitrary and I think is more suitable for a comment.