# different behaviour or sqrt when compiled with 64 or 32 bits

Tags: c, math, 32bit-64bit, sqrt, mpfr

I'm using sqrt() function from math library, when I build for 64 bit using -m64 I'm getting correct result but when I build for 32 bit I have very inconsistent behaviour.

For example on 64bit

```
double dx = 0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023;
sqrt(dx); // => 0x1.fffffffffffffp+511
sqrt(0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023);// => 0x1.fffffffffffffp+511
```

(which I believe is the correctly rounded result, verified with mpfr)

But on 32 bit same input value it behaves differently.

```
double dx = 0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023;
sqrt(dx); // => 0x1.0p+512
sqrt(0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023); // => 0x1.fffffffffffffp+511
```

When the same value passed in a variable I'm getting wrong result.
I checked rounding mode before and after each call and all are set to round to nearest.
What the reason?
I'm using gcc 4.6 on a 64bit machine, and options are `-mfpmath=sse` and `-march=pentium` for both x86 nad x64 cases.

Comment: There seems to be one bug open on this at http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14032, even when I use -msse2 for 32bit i386 code is the one that gets executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't said which compiler or architecure you're using, but assuming `gcc` on `x86` / `x86-64` then the difference is likely down to the fact that by default gcc uses 387 floating point instructions on 32 bit x86, whereas it uses SSE instructions on x86-64.

The 387 floating point registers are 80 bits wide, whereas `double` is 64 bits wide.  This means that intermediate results can have higher precision using the 387 instructions, which can result in a slightly different answer after rounding.  (The SSE2 instructions operate on packed 64 bit doubles).

There's a few ways to change the way the compiler operates, depending on what you want:

- If you use the `-ffloat-store` option on x86 builds, the compiler will discard extra precision whenever you store a value in a `double` variable;
- If you use the `-mfpmath=sse` options on x86 builds, along with `-msse2` or an `-march=` switch that specifies an SSE2-supporting architecture, the compiler will use SSE instructions for floating point just as on x86-64.  The code will only run on CPUs that support SSE2, though (Pentium-M / Pentium 4 and later).
- If you use the `-mfpmath=387` option on x86-64 builds, the compiler will use 387 instructions for floating point just as on x86.  This isn't recommended, though - the x86-64 ABI specifies that floating point values are passed in SSE registers, so the compiler has to do a lot of shuffling between 387 and SSE registers with this option.

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.6 on a 64bit machine, and options are `-mfpmath=sse` and `-march=pentium` for both x86 nad x64 cases. Shoudln't I be getting same result from both cases? I'm mostly interested in 32 bit build so I guess `-mfpmath=387` might give me correct result if there are no other problems

Comment: @giridhart: `-march=pentium` only enables SSE1, which only does single-precision - for double-precision it has to fall back to 387 which has the bonus precision.  You want `-msse2` or `-march=pentium-m` or similar along with `-mfpmath=sse`.

Comment: Actually I use `-mfpmath=sse` and `-msse`, Now I changed to `-mfpmath=sse2` but I still getting wrong result. please suggest correct option for fixing this. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Certain compilers, such as `gcc`, when they see certain math library functions performed on static literals, actually calculate the value during compile time, where-as with the variable, it's by necessity calculated at run-time.  The compile-time value is typically calculated by the compiler using a math library like MPFR, GNU MP, etc., so the results will be more accurate, or at least as accurate as possible from platform-to-platform.

Comment: I also seem to remember that gcc is willing to do compile-time math on literals using 80-bit precision on x86, while a value that's stored into a `double` has to be reduced to 64-bit precision.

Comment: Yes, I think that the reason for correct result when constant is used. Is there a way to fix problem with 32bit library? There is a similar problem listed on stack overflow but it is with C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461319/c-sharp-inconsistent-math-operation-result-on-32-bit-and-64-bit

Comment: @giridhart : From your post it looks as though your 32-bit and 64-bit result with the literal are the same ... are you saying they are different?

Comment: @Jason yeah, I should have added both cases for x64. On x64 both literal and variable case give correct result where as on x86 only the literal case