# C++ / C# differences with float and double

Tags: c#, c++, floating-point, double

We are converting a C++ math library to C#. The library mixes the use of floats and doubles (casting between them sometimes) and we are trying to do the same, in order to get the exact same results in C# that we had in C++ but it is proving to be very difficult if not impossible.

I think the problem is one or more of the following, but I am not an expert:

1. Converting floats to double and double to floats is causing unpredictable results and done differently in C++ and C#
2. C++ and C# handle float precision differently, and they can't mimic each other
3. There is a setting somewhere in .NET to make it perform like C++, but I can't find it (both are 32-bit)

Can somebody explain to me the possible problems and maybe link me to some authoritative documentation from Microsoft I can use to help explain the situation and the reason for the differences?

**EDIT**
We are using VC6 and .NET4.0

I can't give examples of the calculations, because of an NDA, but I can show some numbers for the differences... probably very useless by themselves:

```
 8.085004000000000 (C#) vs. 
 8.084980000000000 (C++)    

 8.848165000000000 (C#) vs. 
 8.848170000000000 (C++)   

 0.015263214111328 (C#) vs. 
 0.015263900756836 (C++)
```

It should be noted that these numbers include compounded problems. These are the results of calculations.

Comment: can you provide one concrete example where you had different results?

Comment: I think it is more to do with the hardware than the language (though I could be wrong). The floating point registers are larger than memory locations (On intel). So if a whole expression is evaluated in the registers you get one result while if a temporary values is stored in memory you will loose some precision and get a slightly different result. Also the C++ compiler may be using generic floating point operations while the .NET JIT compiler may be able to utilize a set of instructions that are more specific and accurate for the architecture.

Comment: @Martin Thanks. So, is it expected to be 100% accurate, or is it expected to have differences between the two?

Comment: Nothing about floating point arithmetic is 100% accurate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ allows the program to retain a higher precision for temporary results than the type of the subexpressions would imply. One thing that can happen is that intermediate expressions (or an unspecified subset of them) are computed as extended 80-bit floats.

<strike>I would be surprised on the other hand if this applied to C#, but</strike> even if it does, the C# compiler doesn't have to choose the same subset of expression to compute as 80-bit extended floats. EDIT: See Eric's comment below.

[More details](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125056)

Another instance of the same intermediate precision problem is when the compiler uses the `fmadd` instruction for what is a multiplication followed by an addition in the source code (if the target architecture has it—for instance, PowerPC). The `fmadd` instruction computes its intermediate result exactly, whereas a normal addition would round the intermediate result.

To prevent the C++ compiler from doing that, you should only need to write floating-point computations as three-address code using volatile variables for intermediate results. If this transformation changes the result of the C++ program, it means that the above problem was at play. But then you have changed the C++-side results. There is probably no way to get the exact same old C++ results in C# without reading the generated assembly.

If it's a little bit old, your C++ compiler may also optimize floating-point computations as if they were associative when they are not. There is not much you can do about that. It's just incorrect. The three-address code transformation would again prevent the compiler from applying it, but again there is no simple way to get the C# compiler to reproduce the old C++ results.

Comment: Thank you. The C++ is VC6, and the C# is using C# is .NET 4.0

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, I refer you to section 4.1.6 of the C# specification, which begins **Floating-point operations may be performed with higher precision than the result type of the operation. For example, some hardware architectures support an “extended” or “long double” floating-point type with greater range and precision than the double type, and implicitly perform all floating-point operations using this higher precision type. ... ** See the spec for more details.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the information. I am surprised that Microsoft included this caveat in its specification, since I would have thought most processors had the SSE instruction set with "real" doubles when they started work on .NET. Java has more guarantees on floating-point computations, for instance (there is a whole article co-authored by Kahan on the subject that this strictness prevents some optimizations and is therefore misapplied. I never which side he's going to be on :)

Comment: Remember, .NET runs on a *lot* of different platforms, from embedded devices to high end servers to mac web browsers running Silverlight. There's no common denominator to the processors really. For some more issues see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342396/why-does-this-floating-point-calculation-give-different-results-on-different-mach