# Explanation of why C++ and C# have a different maximum value for type double?

Tags: c#, c++, types, double, specifications

In C#, the max value for type double is: 1.79769313486232E+308.

However, in C++, the max value for type double is: 1.79769e+308.

This means that a C++ program (using the strtod function) cannot always parse a double type value which has been output by C#.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour and any good solution to deal with the problem?

Comment: Are you comparing the output of `double` values? Then you should note that C++ by default only shows 6 digits for floating point numbers. This can be changed by using [`std::precision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision).

Comment: I'd this question is answers mark it as answered as it float up the search list

Comment: None of the answers or comments are satisfactory, nor is this question a duplicate.  It is more specific.

Comment: No I am not talking about the default output when converting to a string of 6 decimal places.  The min/max listed is from the C++ specification documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From** [C++ / C# differences with float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580389/c-c-sharp-differences-with-float-and-double?rq=1)

> C++ allows the program to retain a higher precision for temporary
>   results than the type of the subexpressions would imply. One thing
>   that can happen is that intermediate expressions (or an unspecified
>   subset of them) are computed as extended 80-bit floats.

**More Info** [Precision and Accuracy in Floating-Point Calculations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/125056/info-precision-and-accuracy-in-floating-point-calculations)

**Quote** *Eric Lippert*

> section 4.1.6 of the C# specification, which begins **Floating-point
>   operations may be performed with higher precision than the result type
>   of the operation. For example, some hardware architectures support an
>   “extended” or “long double” floating-point type with greater range and
>   precision than the double type, and implicitly perform all
>   floating-point operations using this higher precision type. ... ** See
>   the spec for more details.

Comment: You should have just flagged it as a duplicate. Even the Microsoft link is the same

Comment: @MickyD can do still, ill help.. its 4pm and im at work so trying everything i can not to :)

Comment: not a problem good sir :)

Comment: @MickyD i got to 6000 i am happy man, let the weekend begin!

Comment: lol gratz buddy.