# Modulus gives wrong outcome?

Tags: c#, modulus

Could anyone tell me why these two modulus calculations yield two different outcomes? I just need to blame someone or something but me for all those hours I lost finding this bug.

```
public void test1()
{
    int stepAmount = 100;
    float t = 0.02f;
    float remainder = t % (1f / stepAmount);
    Debug.Log("Remainder: " + remainder);
    // Remainder: 0.01

    float fractions = 1f / stepAmount;
    remainder = t % fractions;
    Debug.Log("Remainder: " + remainder);
    // Remainder: 0
}
```

Using VS-2017 V15.3.5

Comment: For what its worth, I can't reproduce this on VS for Mac v7.2 (636). Both remainders are `0.0`

Comment: Dotnetfiddle shows 0 for both results: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XTHswt  I tried the exact same code as what is in the dotnetfiddle link with https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-c-sharp-online and it shows the issue you are describing.

Comment: Reproducible here: https://ideone.com/JHomEl

Comment: Reproduced in VS2017 version 15.4.2.

Comment: what version of visual studio do you use?

Comment: Reproduced with JetBrains Rider 2017.2

Comment: @Donnoh Just added that, but it is not restricted to just this version apparently.

Comment: Oddly behaviour is different if `stepAmount` is const.

Comment: On my machine if I change third line to: float remainder = t % (1f / 100); I'm getting two zeros and same results as you otherwise, but I'd also like to know why.

Comment: Why are you using floats if precision is necessary? Using your version of VS and using decimal will not provide inconsistent results.

Comment: @SamMarion float precision is enough for me. But I just encountered this in my code and find it very strange behavior. There where several ways I could solve it but actually pin pointing the bug I had to these lines took hours, since "it really should return 0".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this floating-point calculation give different results on different machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342396/why-does-this-floating-point-calculation-give-different-results-on-different-mac)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My best bet is that this is due to the liberty the runtime has to perform floating point operations with higher precision than the types involved and then truncating the result to the type's precision when assigning:

> The CLI specification in section 12.1.3 dictates an exact precision for floating point numbers, float and double, when used in storage locations. However it allows for the precision to be exceeded when floating point numbers are used in other locations like the execution stack, arguments return values, etc … What precision is used is left to the runtime and underlying hardware. This extra precision can lead to subtle differences in floating point evaluations between different machines or runtimes.

Source [here](http://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2014/12/22/redundant-cast.html).

In you first example `t % (1f / stepAmount)` can be performed entirely with a higher precision than `float` and then truncated when the result is assigned to `remainder`, while in the second example, `1f / stepAmount` is truncated and assigned to `fractions` prior to the modulus operation.

As to why making `stepamount` a `const` makes both modulus operations consistent, the reason is that `1f / stepamount` immediately becomes a constant expression that is evaluated and truncated to float precision at *compile time* and is no different from writing `0.01f` which essentially makes both examples equivalent.

Comment: I just don't know enough to make a good comment on this but doesn't make the "f" in the `(1f / stepAmount)` operation an entire `float` operation? Also (even more strangely?), making `stepamount` a `const` fixes the issue.

Comment: I think this is correct. When changing the types of t, remainder, and fractions to double in LinqPad I get `Remainder: 0.00999999955296516` for both operations.

Comment: Note that theres just a single `div` instruction in msil. There's no `div` specific for floats or doubles.