# what happens when we divide double by float without any casting?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, double

> Here i have a code (just playing around)

```
using System ;
class program{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float a = 4.246f;
        double b = 8.492;
        System.Console.WriteLine(a*2);
        System.Console.WriteLine(b/a);
    }
}
```

> here expected result is 2 but it is giving a miracle result."2.0000000880453".
> (i knows it will require casting for desired result).
>
> But  my question is how the code is deriving this miracle result. If they are incompatible then why it is not giving an error

Comment: https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

The runtime has the liberty of conducting floating point operations at a higher precision and then truncating on assignment (if necessary). Ultimately, if you divide a double by a float, you will get a double back unless you specifically cast to a float. This can be confirmed with the following:

```
float a = 4.246f;
double b = 8.492;
var c = b/a;
Console.WriteLine(c.GetType()); // System.Double
```

In some cases, even if you assign an operation with floating points to a float, the operation can still be conducted by the runtime at the higher precision. There's an example of this happening in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189863/modulus-gives-wrong-outcome).

Comment: While this is true, it's not the cause of the OP's issue.

Comment: @Sneftel Perhaps I'm misinterpreting the question, but I read it as wondering why an operation involving a float and a double uses the precision of a double instead of the precision of a float. However, it could be the more fundamental question of why floating point arithmetic is imprecise.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure the OP thinks that stuff is getting messed up specifically because he's operating on a float and a double.