# In Debug mode value = 0.66666666666663 and in Console.WriteLine the result is 0.66666666666667

Tags: c#

I'm doing calc like this

```
double sdf = 0.0;
sdf = ((300.0-200.0)/(300.0-150.0));
Console.WriteLine(sdf);
```

Is there a reason for this and why the value is not same?

Comment: they are the same to within an epsilon! :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Also, see: [release mode uses double precision even for float variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277623/release-mode-uses-double-precision-even-for-float-variables)